# Can I plug in the SI unit variants of measurement for this formula?

Tags: si-units, unit-conversion

[Here](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/WindTunnel/Activities/lift_formula.html), NASA gives a formula for aircraft lift:

$$
L = \frac12 d\ v^2 s C_L 
$$
with

- $L =$ Lift, which must equal the airplane's weight in pounds
- $d =$ density of the air. This will change due to altitude. These values can be found in a I.C.A.O. Standard Atmosphere Table.
- $v =$ velocity of an aircraft expressed in feet per second
- $s =$ the wing area of an aircraft in square feet
- $C_L =$ Coefficient of lift , which is determined by the type of airfoil and angle of attack.

The page states that you use feet/sec etc, and get pounds lifted out of it. Will it work for m/s  etc. and kg lifted?

Comment: Have you made any effort to do a dimensional analysis and see what units come out when you do that?

Comment: That is not a question I would ask NASA, however impressive their other achievements, :). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer-No.  For one thing, Kilograms are not a unit of lift

However, determining the whole answer is not a straight-forward process.

First, consider the dimensions: as suggested by @tpg2114

The RHS, Lift, has dimensions of ***force***;  but since $F=ma$, the dimensions of the LHS reduce to $$\frac{Mass \times Length }{Time^2}$$

Now for the RHS.

Ignoring the constant $\frac12$, the first term is $d$, the air density, with dimensions of $\frac{Mass}{Length^3}$;

The second term, $v^2$, has dimensions of $\frac{Length^2}{Time^2}$

The third term, $s$, the area of the wing, has dimensions of $Length^2$

Combining these dimensions into the equation, and assuming for the moment that the coefficient is dimensionless, we get:$$\frac{Mass \times Length }{Time^2}=?\frac{Mass}{Length^3} \times \frac{Length^2}{Time^2} \times  Length^2$$

And indeed, when we cancel out dimensions on the RHS, we find the two sides have the same dimensions.  Our assumption that the coefficient is dimensionless is borne out.

So, it would appear that you can use the SI system with this equation, with one possible problem:  *What units were used for the density of air?*

The question refers to a table;  the units for density of the air in this table are not listed, but a check shows that the tabulated values match the density of air in units of ***slugs/cubic foot***.

So the equation is one in which the dimensions match, and the units used are from the "Foot-Slug-Second" system.  This is a coherent system;  if you use only these units, and units derived from them, formulas work without arbitrary conversion factors  One such derived unit is the Pound-force.

Another such coherent Imperial System is the "Foot-Pound_mass, Second" system, with the derived unit of force the poundal.

Trying to use pounds force and pounds mass in the same formula will lead to chaos...

The SI system, using metres, kilograms and seconds, is also coherent;  the formula will work as written with SI units, and give newtons of lift.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't arbitrarily "plug in numbers" with whatever dimensions you see fit, and expect the results to make sense. When you look at the equations, you will see there are other quantities (like density) that come into play. If you follow the dimensions, you will be able to see whether you can get the right answer or not.

For example, if you start with density in pounds per cubic foot, and multiply by the square of velocity in feet/second and the area of your object in square feet, the units of what you are left with are pounds x feet / second squared. If you use kg/m^3 for density, and m/s for velocity, your result will be in kg m / s^2 - the Newton.

But if there are other scale factors that are dimensional (some of these are empirical) you have to be VERY careful with this kind of thing. As Countto10 pointed out in a comment, NASA has gotten this wrong - as did the SDI folks.

It's somewhat embarassing that we can put a man on the moon but we can't use SI units in the US.

Comment: I never said it was. I was giving a general answer - "for example if" was meant to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use SI units in this formula. It is *dimensionally correct* - the RHS has the units of force (as DJohnM demonstrates), and the LHS is a force. So it does not depend on the system of units used.

When using SI units the answer will be in Newtons, the SI unit of force, not kilograms, the unit of mass.

Answer (score -1):

Emphasis mine:

> Can I plug in the SI unit variants of measurement for this formula?
>
> NASA gives a formula for aircraft lift:
>
> $$
> L = \frac12 d\ v^2 s C_L 
> $$
>   with
>
> - $L =$ Lift, **which must equal the airplane's weight in pounds**
>
> ... The page states that you use feet/sec etc, and get pounds lifted out of it. Will it work for m/s  etc. and kg lifted?

Contrary to the other answers, you can't use that because of the caveat that lift "must equal the airplane's weight in pounds." Pounds are a unit of mass, not force. To use this with S.I. units, one find where lift equals the product of the airplane's mass and acceleration due to gravity $g$.

Newton's second law originally stated that force is proportional to the product of mass and acceleration, or $F=kma$ with $k$ being some unit-dependent constant of proportionality. The metric system does away with that constant of proportionality, resulting in $F=ma$. This is more than a matter of appearance. The form $F=kma$ appears to suggest that force is something fundamentally different than mass, length, and time. It isn't.

While there are many drawbacks to using non-consistent customary units, there are some advantages for Earth-bound usage such as engineering. In particular, it can be quite handy to have weight and mass be numerically equal to one another (more or less). This question, and the linked web page, illustrate just that.

Comment: So what happens to F=ma when you apply a 1 pound force to a 1 pound mass.?

Comment: -1. The "caveat" applied by NASA is not inherent in the equation. This is NASA's mistake, or rather "mis-direction". There is no "must" about it. There is nothing in the equation which restricts the user to the imperial system of units.